# How to type two left braces in vim with Latex-Suite?

Tags: vim, latex-suite

When I type two left braces `{{`, Latex-Suite expands them into `\left\{  \right\}<++>`.  I use markers to organize my files, so needless to say this is very vexing.  Does Latex-Suite provide a way to type two left braces, or is there a way to temporarily toggle its bindings?

Comment: It's a horrible misfeature. There are _at least_ two other ways to insert \left'd brackets that _don't_ keep messing up my equations. There are far more benign features that they let you disable in `tex.vim` …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just simply add a imap to do this for you:

```
inoremap \{{ {{
```

If you define it this way it won't expand the braces in the imap definition, it will just insert the braces.

Comment: I have to go with this one for simplicity, but the other answers are also good.

Comment: Where do you put it? I tried it in `tex.vim`, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: @LukeMaurer you can place it `after/ftplugin/tex.vim` and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable this function globally by commenting out the line

```
call IMAP ('{{', '\left\{ <++> \right\}<++>', "tex")
```

in the `main.vim` of the vim latex plugin.

In my case, it was line 62 in my `~/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim` .

Btw., I have taken this opportunity to also disable the function called when typing `$$`.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the triggering of the mapping defined by the Latex-Suite by inserting the second brace literally via `<C-v>` (often remapped to `<C-q>` on Windows): `{<C-v>{`.

Comment: Well, if you're willing to have to think about it every time, you can always type both and then undo, or type `{ {` and then backspace the space. It's just obnoxious to work around.